# If $2$ coupons are drawn from a bag contains $n$ coupons, find the chance that the difference of coupons exceeds $m$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> A bag contains $n$ coupons marked $1,2,3....n$. If $2$ coupons are drawn, then the chance that the difference of coupons exceeds $m$ (less than $n-1$)

$$
\text{Req. Prob.}=\frac{}{^{n}C_{2}}
$$

The solution given in my reference is $\dfrac{(n-m)(n+m-1)}{n(n-1)}$, but I don't understand the logic used to obtain the numerator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the difference could be $m+1,m+2,...n-2$ and $n-1$.

There is only 1 pair with difference $n-1$

There are 2 pairs with difference $n-2$

There are 3 pairs with difference $n-3$

...

There are $n-m-1$ pairs with difference $m+1$

So, if we sum $$1+2+3+...+(n-m-1) = {(n-m-1)(n-m) \over 2}$$

we get the result.

Answer (score 0):

We can choose two of the $n$ coupons in $\binom n2$ different ways. To count the ways in which we can choose them with difference greater than $m$, choose two out of $n-m$ coupons and then place $m$ further coupons between them, in $\binom{n-m}2$ ways. Thus the probability for the difference to exceed $m$ is

$$
\frac{\binom{n-m}2}{\binom n2}=\frac{(n-m)(n-m-1)}{n(n-1)}\;.
$$

The plus sign in your factor $n+m-1$ is a typo, as you can see if you substitute $m=1$, where your result yields probability $1$, which is clearly not the probability for the difference to exceed $1$.